# Carousel not working in Bootstrap, jQuery issue?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

New to Bootstrap, no clue with Java/jQuery.
I found this cool snippet at: http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/carousel-extended  but I'm screwing it up somehow. Visually everything looks fine but the slides aren't moving and clicking on the thumbnails doesn't make a change either. I went through the html and nothing is jumping out at me, which makes me think maybe it's the javascript? Does anyone see something I'm missing? It's probably a dumb mistake. Thanks!

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper"> 
    <div class="container">

            <!--logo-->
            <header>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span4 logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/marlin-logo.png"></a>
                    </div>

                        <div class="span3 socialbox pull-right">

                        <div class="social-icons">
                         <a id="facebook" href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/facebook.png"></a>
                         <a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/twitter.png"></a>
                         <a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/flickr.png"></a>
                         <a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/pinterest.png"></a>
                         <a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/instragram.png"></a>
                         <a href="#"><img src="img/social_icons/mail.png"></a>
                         </div><!--end social-icons --> 
                    </div><!--end span3 -->                     
                </div><!--end row -->   
            </header>



            <!--Nav-->  
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">


                <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </a>


                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Components<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                               <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end Nav-->
      </div>
        <!--end container-->


        <div class="container">

                        <!-- Slider -->
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span12" id="slider">
                                        <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                <div class="span8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                                                                <!-- Carousel items -->
                                                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                                                        <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one" /></div>
                                                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two" /></div>
                                                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three" /></div>
                                                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="3"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four" /></div>
                                                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="4"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five" /></div>
                                                                        <div class="item" data-slide-number="5"><img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six" /></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                                                                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                                                                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="span4" id="carousel-text"></div>

                                                <div style="display: none;" id="slide-content">
                                                        <div id="slide-content-0">
                                                                <h2>Slider One</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div id="slide-content-1">
                                                                <h2>Slider Two</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div id="slide-content-2">
                                                                <h2>Slider Three</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div id="slide-content-3">
                                                                <h2>Slider Four</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div id="slide-content-4">
                                                                <h2>Slider Five</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div id="slide-content-5">
                                                                <h2>Slider Six</h2>
                                                                <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                                                <p class="sub-text">October 24 2012 - <a href="#">Read more</a></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>

                                </div>
                        </div> <!--/Slider-->

                        <div class="row-fluid hidden-phone" id="slider-thumbs">
                                <div class="span12">
                                        <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                                        <ul class="thumbnails">
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="span2">
                                                        <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5">
                                                                <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
</div>
</div><!--end container-->


            <div id="footer">
                <p>&copy; 2013 Blue Marlin Template designed by <a href="http://www.jannahill.com" target="_blank">Janna Hill</a> | All Rights Reserved. </p>
            </div>
            <!-- end footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper  -->



<!-- start: Java Script -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
<!-- end: Java Script -->


<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                interval: 5000
        });

        $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

        //Handles the carousel thumbnails
        $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
                var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
                var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
                var id = parseInt(id);
                $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
        });


        // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
                var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
        });


});
</script>
```

Comment: You have names of Javascript files in your Javascript that aren't commented, a HTML comment that won't be escaped in Javascript, no libraries (including jQuery and Bootstrap.js) and also you're missing the `j` in `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I actually don't understand how to fix any of that (other than the missing j) since I was copy/pasting code and don't know javascript. Is there any way you could explain what I need to change?
http://jannahill.com/bluemarlin/about.html  shows what's happening now.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle of the original code at http://jsfiddle.net/markusm/VvdBH/. My suggestion would be to start working with that and then you can see how the changes work out before you apply them to your website. A tiny little bit of background knowledge about JavaScript and jQuery might also be unavoidable. Have a look at the nice w3scools tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Thanks. I tried pasting in your code and am having the same results. The carousel won't move and clicking a thumbnail doesn't change anything either. I'll try watching the tut but I don't even know what to try and change.

Comment: Did you reference the necessary javascript-libraries and include the original script in your html page? In the jsfiddle this is separated. You have to include at least jquery and bootstrap.js before you include the <script>-part.

Comment: Fixed a small mistake in my original [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markusm/VvdBH/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML works fine, so most likely the references to the needed JavaScript-files are not correct. I created a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/markusm/Tf6S7/1/ that works. What I did was simply to use your code and add references to the needed Twitter Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript Files. What you have to do with your HTML-code is:

Add

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

to the `<head>`-section (if you did not already have that reference anyway).

And instead of the JavaScript references you use so far (the block between `<!-- start: Java Script -->` and `<!-- end: Java Script -->`) add the following:

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

This will make sure you reference the correct JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

@Jannak I had a working demo of it, which you will find [here](https://github.com/Vishmay/bootstrap-carousel). Hope this helps you.